# Filling Balance sheet in ITR4 for freelancers

Tags: income-tax, india, business

I'm trying to fill ITR 4 for the first time. I'm a salaried professional with a side income from freelancing. I earned around 3 Lacs plus from freelancing.

In ITR 4 there is a section - Part A Balance Sheet and Part A Profit Loss.
But me being a freelancer am I required to fill the details in the Balance sheet and Profit and loss section which are mostly irrelevant to me. I simply develop some websites and get paid through paypal.

Plz advice

Answer (score 1):

ITR-4 is for incorporated business.

For freelancing, You can fill ITR 2 and declare the freelancing income as "income from other source".

Refer to the Income Tax [website](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/) for more details

Comment: but using itr 2 i can't claim deductions like internet charges etc for income from other source

Comment: You have to declare only the net income, less of expenses. Maintain proper records. Get the help of a CA for as less as Rs 2000.